# Can I Use 'Should' For Obligations In The Past?

Tags: modal-verbs

For example, can I say:

> My manager said if Mr. Smith arrived late, I should call her immediately.

Clearly, I cannot use "should have called" here as it implies that I didn't call at all, which is not what I mean.

So, do I need to change "should" to "had to" or "was supposed to" or is it fine to use "should" here?

Thank you.

Comment: From your question,  it's unclear what you mean.  Did Mr. Smith actually arrive late?  if so,  you can say 'should have '. If not,  please add more detail about the situation.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, it's hard to know exactly what you wish to communicate.  The sentence as currently written sounds fine to me.  It tells me that at some point in the past, your manager said something equivalent to "if Mr Smith arrives late, you should call me immediately".  It does not tell me whether Mr Smith arrived late, or arrived at all, or whether you did or didn't call.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Yes. That is what I mean. I don't want to convey whether Mr. Smith actually arrived or not. I only want to report the fact that the manager assigned such a task to me.

Comment: In that case I think your sentence is fine.